# No file type_mat.hpp in glm/detail

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, glm-math

On Linux I use those includes

```
#include <glm/detail/type_mat.hpp>
#include <glm/detail/type_vec.hpp>
```

I noticed that thes files only exist in the `/usr/include/glm` source folder and not in the sources provided with my code. There are some `type_mat*x*.hpp` for each matrix dimension but not the basic one.
Then I tried running this on windows 10 VisualStudio and it can't find those files.
I checked a recent version of glm and there are not present again.

So my questions are :
Why are those files only in my package installed version of glm on linux ?
Are they automately generated ?
What is the right solution for windows ? Including `#include <glm/glm.hpp>` everywhere seems to work but I think its not so clean.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone curious about this, here is my investigation:

**Start from version glm-0.9.5**, we can clear saw `type_mat.hpp`

[image]

The later on version, I can not found such file anylonger:

[image]

So, answer the first question, this file doesn't autogenerated.

You can also verify this from glm github releases.

Solution:

My solution is stay with glm-0.9.5. However, it was old.

If we using more decent version, We might comment #include that file out.

**update 05/13/2022**

Acutually you don't need to include type_mat.hpp anylonger in newer glm, it can just be built, just include glm/glm.hpp and trasnformation.